# Could somebody please identify this bicycle?

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

I have been looking into purchasing a second hand road bicycle for my daily commute. I went through many possibilities and would like to know if any of you have seen or can identify the attached. Do you know how much it is worth and is it any good?

[image: Bicycle in question]

Many thanks in advance,
F.

Comment: I'm not sure that a fixie is a good idea for a commuter bike.  (Or is that a coaster brake on the rear?)

Comment: @DanielRHicks - I think thats a Nexus IGH with a roller brake.

Comment: @batman it definitely has a cable on the downtube going somewhere, but that could be the rear brake cable or a IGH cable.  The rear dropouts show the bike was built like this, not a conversion.  No rear rim brake means its got to be a drum brake visible.  Looks like a great wee commuter, all it needs is mudguards.   Horizontal top-tubes forever!

Comment: We don't do valuations.  Its worth whatever someone pays for it.

Comment: @Criggie - The cable you see is infront of the spokes which means its going on the drive side which would be a shift cable, not a brake cable. Plus, there are 3 cables leaving the handlebars. It looks like it'd be a decent commuter, but identifying it seems to be hard without any markings and a fairly generic looking frame (and no serial number or anything). I'd guess that someone built this bike up from scratch though with a non-branded frame (or they stripped all the decals).